# Why is this giving a syntax error?

Tags: python-3.x

```
CutPrices=[(1,5),(2,6),(3,2)]
CutPrices=sorted(CutPrices)

RodLength=int(input("Enter Rod Length =>"))

def CutRod(p, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    q =float(-inf)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
            q = max(q, p[i-1][1] + CutRod(p, n-p[i-1][0])
    return q

print(CutRod(CutPrices,RodLength))
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced. Any decent IDE would tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a right parenthesis on this line:

```
q = max(q, p[i-1][1] + CutRod(p, n-p[i-1][0]))
                                             ^
```